# How solve system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How to solve system linear of equations? I'm so confused I don't know how to find the result.
$$
\begin{array}{rcr}
2p - 2q - r + 3s &=& 4 \\ 
p - q +2s &=& 1 \\
-2p +2q -4s &=& -2 \end{array}
$$
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [Gauss-Jordan elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). The operations are
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
2 & -2 & -1 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
-2 & 2 & 0 & -4 & -2
\end{array}\right]
\xrightarrow{(1/2)\cdot R_{1}\to R_{1}}\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2} & 2 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
-2 & 2 & 0 & -4 & -2
\end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{
\begin{array}{rcr}
R_{2}-R_{1} &\to& R_{2} \\
R_{3}+2\cdot R_{1} &\to& R_{3} \\
\end{array}}\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2} & 2 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{2\cdot R_{2}\to R_{2}}\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2} & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{
\begin{array}{rcrcr}
R_{1}+1/2\cdot R_{2} &\to& R_{1} \\
R_{3}+R_{2} &\to& R_{3} \\
\end{array}}\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
These steps show that 
$$
\operatorname{rref}\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
2 & -2 & -1 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
-2 & 2 & 0 & -4 & -2
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & -1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
The variables $\{p, r\}$ correspond pivot columns and are called "dependent" variables. The other variables $\{q, s\}$ are called "free" variables. To find the general solution to the system, we write each dependent variable in terms of the free variables. This gives 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
p \\
q \\
r \\
s
\end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{r}
q - 2 \, s + 1 \\
q \\
-s - 2 \\
s
\end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
0 \\
-2 \\
0
\end{array}\right]+q\left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right]+s\left[\begin{array}{r}
-2 \\
0 \\
-1 \\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$